Should you report an account you think is bought online?
I noticed a user post a question that looked rather basic. I looked at their previous answers formulated in an other style and have a sort of senior level (even on answers from more then 10 years ago)!
I have a strong feeling there is another person on the account. This could be:

Plain wrong, and my suspicions are completely incorrect.
Correct, because of an oversight (was logged in on someone else computer)
Correct, because this person has sold his account to a new programmer.

What I could find is that selling your account is a little bit frowned upon to do this:
Selling Stack Overflow accounts
But my main question is, should you do anything if you suspect something?

I'd say yes in general, though since the potential fallout of getting it wrong, I'd use one of the private methods available to you. On bigger sites, mods might not be aware of everything going on simply due to the volume of posts.
If you suspect something like that - either flagging, or escalating via the contact us link would be the way to go.
Which approach is a little tricky - you're restricted to how much you can type in a flag, and a mod would need to follow up anyway but there's a better trail of what happened. Using the contact link means there's better privacy, a ticket generated at the community team's end, and it skips a step. Both are 'right', but which is better depends. In either case give as much information as you can.
